# Updating SendGrid contact custom fields via SendGrid API. Why isn't this working?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to update my SendGrid contacts and can't figure out why my attempts to update my contacts' custom fields are not working. My reserved fields (first_name, last_name, email) update, but my custom fields do not. Any ideas why?

Documentation here: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact

````
    try:
        headers = {
            'authorization': f"Bearer {settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY}",
        }
        data = {
            "list_ids": [
                # "Users" list
                "7c2...d20"
            ],
            "contacts": [{
                "email": user.email,
                "first_name": user.first_name,
                "last_name": user.last_name,
                "custom_fields": {
                    "educator_role": user.educator_role,
                }
            }]
        }

        response = requests.put("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
        if(response.status_code != 202):
            capture_message(f"Could not add user with email {user.email} to Sendgrid.", level="error")
    except:
        capture_message(f"Adding/updating SendGrid contact failed for {user.email}.", level="error")```
````

Comment: It's startling that this is not mentioned AT ALL in the docs. Found this github thread on the same topic, cross-linking... https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/953

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unlike reserved fields, updating a custom field requires you pass the custom field `id` instead of the field `name` in your call. So instead of `educator_role`, use the id, it will be something random like `e1_T`.

You can get the id via the [/marketing/field_definitions](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/custom-fields/get-all-field-definitions) endpoint.

Comment: Ahh amazing, can't test it now but throwing that on my Jira board for another day. Thank you!

Comment: What an odd API. So I define a custom field by name in the Sendgrid dashboard, en then it doesn't show me an id anywhere and now I have to call an endpoint to find out. I really don't understand why they didn't allow the use of field names and map it to the id internally. Seems like a bad design choice to have to expose the internal details even though there can be only one target when you specify the name.

Comment: I have a production and a development account. Both will have different ids for the field names depending on in what order the fields were defined. Brilliant :\

Comment: Good grief I am so sick of Sendgrid's API being backwards, confusing, or just plain lying.  I found a completely different API page to get custom fields and this was not it.  Thank you.

Comment: Luckily, you can also look in the browser console when on the Custom Fields page and find the request to https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/field_definitions and you will see the custom field IDs in the response data.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Matt, to update a custom field value via SendGrid API, we need to refer to the custom field by its ID, not by the field name.
To get a list with your custom field IDs, do:

```py
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient


SENDGRID_API_KEY="print-your-key-here"

sg = SendGridAPIClient(SENDGRID_API_KEY)
response = sg.client.marketing.field_definitions.get()

print(response.body)
```

Also, take a look at the docs: https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/custom-fields/get-all-field-definitions.

##### The custom field ID has logic

For custom fields, the unique ID always starts with the suffix `e`. Followed by an integer number that represents the creation order of the custom fields on the SendGrid platform, p.e. `1, 2, 3`. Followed by underscore `_`. Followed by a letter that represents the custom field type:

- N - Number
- T - Text
- D - Date

Here is an example of a custom field ID list:

```json
{
    "custom_fields":[
        {"id":"e1_N","name":"number_field_test","field_type":"Number"},
        {"id":"e2_T","name":"text_field_test","field_type":"Text"},
        {"id":"e3_D","name":"data_field_test","field_type":"Date"}
    ]
}
```